# How to use the android support percent using xml resoureces value if percentage is not allowed?

Tags: android, resources, android-support-library

I've found this interesting lib from Google

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html

and the use is very simple just add this dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}
```

and this is the code

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
      app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
      app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
      app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

but this is what I'd like to have in order to support portrait/landscape layout for example

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_widthPercent="@dimen/width_percent"
          app:layout_heightPercent="@dimen/height_percent"
          app:layout_marginTopPercent="@dimen/margin_top_percent"
          app:layout_marginLeftPercent="@dimen/margin_left_percent"/>
    </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

The problem is that I want to use resources to speciy the percent value, but the simbol % is not allowed in integer, fraction, dimension and strings don't work.

Why use value from 0% to 100% when it was possibile to use value from 0 to 1 and use resources correctly? :-(

Answer (score 4):

You can define like this:

```
<fraction name="width_percent">80%</fraction>
```

[Here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/C8oaLunpEEj) is blog of percent library.